# Transfer file securely android to pc via LAN

Tags: applications, adb, security, file-transfer

I need a file transfer from android device to pc server.Both of them is in same network.First i tried file transfer via adb.But adb is not secure connection.

How do i securely transfer between android and pc in LAN ?

Comment: What precisely are you trying to protect against?

Comment: transfers are happening in wifi network.only server machine can see packets.unauthorized clients should not  see packets while transferring with 3.party programs(e.g wireshark) what is inside.

Answer (score 1):

[BTSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bittorrent.sync) is one way to go, 
another way is to install [ssh server](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=sshd%20server&c=apps) and use rsync/scp to copy what ever you need.

Comment: is there a library for embedding scp to my developing android application ?

Comment: @remotecommando This site is for Android *users*, so you can only expect answers that are useful to end users, not answers to help you write an app.